# ASP.NET count boxes and then execute popup from same button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Ok, I hope I can explain this well enough.

I have one or more third party Up/Down Spinner+Textbox controls on my page that are black boxes that I can't change the source for.

I want the user to change the UpDownControl contents to choose a quantity and then click a calendar button which will:

1. Add the quantity of all Up/Down boxes.
2. Call a javascript popup to display a calendar with the count from step 1 in the url "...calendar.asp?qty=5".

My problem is getting the two steps to execute in the same click.  As it stands I can click the button once and it counts 
the items and adds them to the popup string and then I have to click it a second time to actually execute the JS popup window.

The code was originally written to "load up" the counts into a second button and then programmatically click it but that looks
like a popup to the browsers since the user didn't click *that* button.

Here is what I have so far that almost works --

On my page:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnPrepCal" runat="server" Text="PrepCal" OnClick="btnPrepCal_Click" ImageUrl="~/images/Calendar.gif"/>
```

In code behind:

```
public void btnPrepCal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
StringBuilder sbParams = new StringBuilder();  

int TotalQty = 0;
int basketItemCount = 0;
int rowIndex = 0;
string Sku = string.Empty;

foreach (GridViewRow varRow in VariantGrid.Rows)
{
    int qnty = GetControlValue(varRow, "Quantity", 0);
    if (qnty > 0)
    {
        basketItemCount++;
        string optionList = (string)VariantGrid.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value;
        ProductVariant variant = _VariantManager.GetVariantFromOptions(optionList);

        if (variant != null)
        {
            BasketItem basketItem = GetBasketItem(optionList, varRow);      
            if (basketItem != null)
            {
                TotalQty += basketItem.Quantity;                    
                Sku = variant.Sku;                          
            }
        }
    }
    rowIndex++;
}
if(Sku.Length > 4) Sku = Sku.Substring(0,4);
sbParams.Append(string.Format("?sku={0}&Qty={1}", Sku, TotalQty));
string popup = string.Empty;
popup = string.Format("window.open('http://trustedtours.org/store/egalaxycalendar.asp{0}','Reservation Calendar','width=265,height=465')",sbParams.ToString());
btnPrepCal.OnClientClick = popup;
```

}

I'm new to .NET and web programming so I'm probably going at it totally backwards so any help is appreciated.  I apologize if it's not clear what I'm trying to do or how.  If you need any more info please ask - the rest of the file is a lot of shopping cart mumbo jumbo so I left it out, I hope it's enough.

---- **update** ----
After looking at the referenced pages I get:

```
Type cstype = this.GetType();
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;             
StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
cstext1.Append("<script type=text/javascript>" + popup + "<script>");
cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "PopupCalendar", cstext1.ToString());
```

And I believe this is added after I set the value of popup near the bottom of my Click handler above, removing the OnClientClick part, right?

Should this popup the other window on a page reload after clicking the button?  (I hate being a newb and asking what's probably obvious questions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're aiming for using the [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) method.  Instead of assigning the OnClientClick method of the button to your JS popup code, set that code to run when the page is reloaded using the RegisterStartupScript method.

This page has some good examples:  http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/JavaScript_with_ASP_NET_2_0_Pages_Part1.aspx

Comment: The update looks correct.  Have you tried it?  I believe the script by default gets injected at the bottom of your page (just before the closing form tag).  See if it is in the HTML source after the page refreshes.  If so perhaps the popup is being blocked.

Comment: It's a UC so I'd expect to see it at the bottom of that control.  I get the refresh when clicking but no sign of it in the view-source.

Comment: I found it!  If it's in a user control you need to call it with ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript and a couple of slight changes in the parameters.  It works!  Thanks so much for your help and for Matt's too!

Answer (score 1):

Ken is correct.  To add to his answer and clarify why your code was *not* working - you were assigning the click-handler of your button to do a popup, but only *after* it was clicked.  This is why you only saw the popup after the 2nd click - the handler was not there the first time you clicked it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes an important piece 'click' for me.